Cilium on Kubernetes: Unreachable Endpoints on Specific Nodes
I'm currently facing an issue with Cilium in my Kubernetes cluster where certain endpoints are unreachable on specific nodes. I'm using Cilium to manage network policies and connectivity within the cluster.
Context:

Kubernetes Cluster: Version 1.28 (kubeadm)
Cilium: Version 1.14.3
Cilium Health Daemon: Enabled

Some of my nodes (172.8.8.3 in the local network) are reachable via ICMP and HTTP, but specific endpoints on these nodes are not responding, leading to errors in Cilium pod logs (on the master):
level=error msg="cannot extract endpoint ID from DNS request" DNSRequestID=6364 dnsName=126.1.0.10.in-addr.arpa. error="Cannot find endpoint with IP 172.8.8.3" ipAddr="172.8.8.3:43426" subsys=fqdn/dnsproxy
level=error msg="cannot find matching endpoint" error="DNS request cannot be associated with an existing endpoint" l3n4Addr="172.8.8.3:43426" subsys=daemon

Health status command :
# cilium-health status
Probe time:   2024-08-09T15:43:39Z
Nodes:
  master (localhost):
    Host connectivity to 10.22.80.14:
      ICMP to stack:   OK, RTT=578.305µs
      HTTP to agent:   OK, RTT=425.9µs
    Endpoint connectivity to 10.0.0.236:
      ICMP to stack:   OK, RTT=529.139µs
      HTTP to agent:   OK, RTT=722.39µs
  worker:
    Host connectivity to 172.8.8.3:
      ICMP to stack:   OK, RTT=680.832µs
      HTTP to agent:   OK, RTT=596.321µs
    Endpoint connectivity to 10.0.2.219:
      ICMP to stack:   Connection timed out
      HTTP to agent:   Get "http://10.0.2.219:4240/hello": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Commands Executed and Results:

Checking Cilium Endpoints:

cilium endpoint list from the cilium agent running on the master node shows that the IP 172.8.8.3 is not present among the managed endpoints.


Overall Cilium Status:

cilium status from the cilium pod agent running on the master node indicates that the node with ip 172.8.8.3 (the worker node) is reachable, but the associated endpoint is unreachable.


Cluster Health Status:

cilium-health status shows that ICMP and HTTP connection attempts to the endpoints 10.0.2.219 fail on my worker node.



Questions:

What could be causing the endpoints on these specific nodes to be unreachable, even though the nodes themselves are reachable?
Are there any additional checks I should perform at the Cilium or Kubernetes level to resolve this issue?
Could this issue be related to network configuration or Cilium's eBPF rules, and how can I verify this?

Thank you in advance for your help

I finally found the solution to my networking problem.
My Kubernetes cluster was modifying the iptables rules on my nodes. When I deleted Kubernetes resources such as MetalLB, Cilium, or others, these rules didn't seem to be removed from the iptables. I'm not sure if this is expected behavior from Kubernetes or not.
To resolve this, I decided to flush my iptables and rebuild them without the unnecessary rules. Here's the process I followed:

First, I saved the current iptables rules to a file:
iptables-save > my-iptables.v4


Then, I edited this file to remove all Cilium-related rules.

Finally, I reloaded the modified rules:
iptables-restore < my-iptables.v4



This process effectively cleaned up my iptables rules, removing the lingering entries from deleted Kubernetes resources.
Then, I reinstall the CNI Cilium. And no errors appear.
